# Images in one of the folders not loading in Azure static web app

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-web-app-routing

We have a Blazor WASM application which is hosted in azure static web app.
We have images in 2 folders

```
/images
/data_images
```

The images from the /images folder is loading in the web app, but the images form the /data_images is not loading and we get 404. I have copied the same images into the /data_images folder but its not loading.

I tried renaming the data_images folder name, but that also doesn't work

Here is my staticwebapp.config.json

```
{
"trailingSlash": "auto",
"routes": [
],
"navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "index.html",
    "exclude": [ "/images/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}", "/imagess/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}", "/data_images/*", "/css/*" ]
},
"mimeTypes": {
    ".json": "text/json",
    ".png": "image/png",
    ".svg": "image/svg+xml"
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried changing `"/data_images/*"` in your .json file to `"/data_images/*.{png,jpg,gif,svg}"` so it matches the functioning folder?

Comment: please remove "exclude" in your "staticwebapp.config.json" and try.
Will Post answer in detail

Comment: Hi @Nick.Mc I tried that but that doesn't work.

Comment: @SaiVamshiKrishna I tried excluding but that also is not working

Comment: I will share my code snippets in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

In your "staticwebapp.config.json," you have an "exclude" rule for "/data_images/*," which means requests to the "/data_images" folder will be excluded from navigation fallback to "index.html." Ensure that this exclusion is not preventing the images from being served. If you want to serve images from this folder, you should remove this exclusion.

**Here I have Tried excluding Rule:**

Added Images in ***index.razor*** page

```
@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle> 
<h1>Hello, world!</h1> 
Welcome to your new app.
<!-- Reference an image from the "/images" folder -->
<img src="/images/BrandBlazor.png" alt="BrandBlazor" />

<!-- Reference an image from the "/data_images" folder -->
<img src="/data_images/images.png" alt="images" /> 
<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

***launchSettings.json***

```
{
    "trailingSlash": "auto",
    "routes": [],
    "navigationFallback": {
      "rewrite": "index.html"
    },
    "mimeTypes": {
      ".json": "text/json",
      ".png": "image/png",
      ".svg": "image/svg+xml"
    }
  }
```

**Deploy your code to static webapp**
**Result**
[image]

Comment: Hi @SaiVamshiKrishna I tried this, but for some reason this is not working for me.

Comment: Ensure that the `/data_images` folder is located at the root level of your web app
and In your `staticwebapp.config.json` file, you have excluded `/data_images/*` from navigation fallback, which means any request to files in this folder will not be redirected to `index.html`.If you want the images to be handled by your app's routing, you may need to remove this exclusion.



Please refer this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration)