# SVG Images not loading in Azure static web app

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-web-app-routing

We have a Blazor WASM application and is hosted in Azure static web app.

The svg images are not loading and we get 404 error.

Do we need to add any entries in staticwebapp.config.json to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Images in one of the folders not loading in Azure static web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77057207/images-in-one-of-the-folders-not-loading-in-azure-static-web-app)

Comment: Hi @MarkusMeyer This was another question I have posted which doesn't have any answers as of now